# How to define an alias without executing dollar signs contained inside?

Tags: bash, alias

I have the alias : `alias gwanip=echo "$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)`. This works fine except I just realized that it executes the command dig everytime bashrc is sourced. How do I keep the functionality of it (ie echo my ip up calling gwanip) but without it running everytime bashrc is sourced ?

Comment: @Rahul I don't want it to query opendns when I `source /etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: Sorry, but this command is not even valid syntax. First, it is missing a closing quotation mark. Second, it defines an alias `gwanip` to `echo` and then tries to show an alias expansion(!) for the IP address that results from the `dig` command, which would certainly give an error. So, please use copy&paste to cite command lines here. In addition, even if you really meant to write `alias gwanip="echo $(...)"`, it would only alias `gwanip` to the target IP _at the moment of definition,_ so the alias would always give the same result when called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape the dollar sign, or remove the useless `echo $( ... )` and just have

```
alias gwanip="dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"
```

or use a shell function instead:

```
function gwanip {
  dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
}
```

With shell functions, you could even create a more generic `shortdig` function and call that.

```
function shortdig {
  dig +short "$1" "$2"
}

function gwanip {
  shortdig "myip.opendns.com" "@resolver1.opendns.com"
}
```

The `bash` manual contains the statement

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

Comment: I was using echo because I didn't say it but I'm outputing `IP : $(dig ...)` among other things, so the real answer is escaping dollar signs unless you know a trick to concatenate strings without using echo.

Comment: @ChiseledAbs I'm not sure I understand. With `gwanip` as a function calling `dig` or as an alias for `dig` (without `echo`) you'd just use `$(gwanip)`... I don't see the use of including the `echo` at all.

Answer (score 4):

Escaping the dollar signs  does the trick.